# Bootstrap Table Plugin export option

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-table, tableexportjs

I'm using https://bootstrap-table.com/ plugins to search, have a pagination, sort a table in my HTML page, every feature work except for the export function. I've been lurking on forums for a few hours now and the only answer that seem to work is just use another plugin, but Bootstrap tables are really friendlier to the eye in my opinion.
I've run and added the requirements for the plugin itself, and added the https://github.com/hhurz/tableExport.jquery.plugin requirements too but i can't find a way to get to this result https://live.bootstrap-table.com/example/extensions/export.html, even with another online editor it fails, although i can't see any resources being loaded locally...
For the moment my HTML page looks like this (I'm working on Django if that matters in any ways):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <!-- Loading main stylesheets -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'main/main.css' %}">
    <!-- Loading icon -->
    <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="{% static 'favicon.ico' %}"/>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div id="toolbar">
        <select class="form-control">
          <option value="">Export Basic</option>
          <option value="all">Export All</option>
          <option value="selected">Export Selected</option>
        </select>
      </div>
      <table class="table" id="table"
        data-toggle="table"
        data-toolbar="#toolbar"
        data-show-export="true"
        data-pagination="true"
        data-search="true"
        data-side-pagination="server"
        data-click-to-select="true"
        data-toolbar="#toolbar"
        data-show-toggle="true"
        data-show-columns="true"
        >
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th scope="col">#</th>
            <th scope="col">First</th>
            <th scope="col">Last</th>
            <th scope="col">Handle</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <th scope="row">1</th>
            <td>Mark</td>
            <td>Otto</td>
            <td>@mdo</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th scope="row">2</th>
            <td>Jacob</td>
            <td>Thornton</td>
            <td>@fat</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th scope="row">3</th>
            <td>Larry</td>
            <td>the Bird</td>
            <td>@twitter</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha512-bLT0Qm9VnAYZDflyKcBaQ2gg0hSYNQrJ8RilYldYQ1FxQYoCLtUjuuRuZo+fjqhx/qtq/1itJ0C2ejDxltZVFg==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-table@1.17.1/dist/bootstrap-table.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-table@1.17.1/dist/bootstrap-table.min.css">
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-table@1.17.1/dist/bootstrap-table.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified Locales -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-table/1.17.1/locale/bootstrap-table-en-US.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

But no way to see the export button, am i missing some dependencies or something?
I can include my working tree but again, it's a basic Django app tree, since all resources look like they are being loaded from URLs, and even the top URLs from the official example https://examples.bootstrap-table.com/index.html#extensions/export.html#view-source don't help...

Thanks in advance for any help you could provide

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I can see you forgot to add a lot of libraries from the example. See more in snippet.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    
    <!-- just added all required libraries from your example site -->
    <link href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-table@1.17.1/dist/bootstrap-table.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/tableexport.jquery.plugin/tableExport.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/tableexport.jquery.plugin/libs/jsPDF/jspdf.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/tableexport.jquery.plugin/libs/jsPDF-AutoTable/jspdf.plugin.autotable.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-table@1.17.1/dist/bootstrap-table.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-table@1.17.1/dist/extensions/export/bootstrap-table-export.min.js"></script>
    

  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div id="toolbar" class="select">
        <select class="form-control">
          <option value="">Export Basic</option>
          <option value="all">Export All</option>
          <option value="selected">Export Selected</option>
        </select>
      </div>
      <table class="table" id="table"
        data-toggle="table"
        data-toolbar="#toolbar"
        data-show-export="true"
        data-pagination="true"
        data-search="true"
        data-side-pagination="server"
        data-click-to-select="true"
        data-toolbar="#toolbar"
        data-show-toggle="true"
        data-show-columns="true"
        >
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th scope="col">#</th>
            <th scope="col">First</th>
            <th scope="col">Last</th>
            <th scope="col">Handle</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <th scope="row">1</th>
            <td>Mark</td>
            <td>Otto</td>
            <td>@mdo</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th scope="row">2</th>
            <td>Jacob</td>
            <td>Thornton</td>
            <td>@fat</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th scope="row">3</th>
            <td>Larry</td>
            <td>the Bird</td>
            <td>@twitter</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
    
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I already tried all these libraries but as dumb as it sounds, I think i read somewhere to put JS scripts in the body tags, but putting them between the head tags seems to solve my problem...